# FlyingSaucer ITextRenderer finish errors (unbalanced save/restore and blank PDFs)

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer

I am using Flying Saucer with IText in order to generate PDFs from an HTML file, specifically utilizing the `org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer` class. My code is simple. The generation code is encapsulated in a method like so:

```
/* PDfGenerator class only has ONE instance */
public PdfGenerator() {
    this.renderer = new ITextRenderer(); //This is a class variable that only gets instantiated ONCE
}

public void generatePDF(String outputFilePath, String htmlContent) {
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(htmlContent);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(new BufferedOutputStream(
          new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFilePath)), BUFFER_SIZE), true);
    renderer.finishPDF();
}
```

EDIT:

My generator class is actually managed by Spring as a singleton object. I have a manager class that has an ExecutorService acting as a queue for PDF generation tasks. This manager uses the singleton Generator to generate objects. Therefore I instantiate the ITextRenderer just ONCE and just reuse it. Now I set my queue to operate up to 2 threads concurrently. I just realized if maybe this is causing the, because I encounter situations where TWO threads are using my ONE renderer to render two separate sets of PDFs.

Now, I just realized that I am actually calling "finish" twice per render! One in the `createPDF()`errors call (passing true as the second parameter), and one explicit call to `finishPDF()`.

This has been running for quite some time now, and it's managed to generate PDFs successfully *most* of the time. I've been encountering 2 different types of errors sporadically:

1. A runtime exception due to unbalanced save/restore state operators. Sample stacktrace as follows:

   ```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unbalanced save/restore state operators.
   at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.restoreState(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.0.8.jar:na]
   at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextOutputDevice.setClip(ITextOutputDevice.java:737) ~[core-renderer-R8.jar:na]
   at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.paintPage(ITextRenderer.java:387) ~[core-renderer-R8.jar:na]
   at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.writePDF(ITextRenderer.java:348) ~[core-renderer-R8.jar:na]
   at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.createPDF(ITextRenderer.java:315) ~[core-renderer-R8.jar:na]
   at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.createPDF(ITextRenderer.java:280) ~[core-renderer-R8.jar:na]
   ```
2. The PDF generated has missing/deformed sections or at worst, a blank page.

For Issue 2, I am fairly confident it's due to calling finishPDF() twice. However, for Issue 1, it occurs *before* the calls to finishPDF() are executed, so I actually don't know if that's what's causing the problem.

Has anyone had experience dealing with these 2 issues while using Flying Saucer together with iText?

Comment: Can you post your full FS code please? Eg. where you set your document. For 2: Do you use CSS, pagebreaktags etc.? This can sometimes cause empty page, maybe there are some empty lines on the end of the file or there's not enough space for a picture.

Comment: Btw. what happens if you remove the `finishPDF()` call? `createPDF` with parameter `finish = true` (as you've set) doesn't need a second finish (however it shouldn't affect your pdf in a negative way).

Comment: Hi @ollo, added more details to the question. I also realized maybe I was actually accessing one instance of the renderer concurrently which could possibly be the reason I encounter the issues mentioned above. I originally designed it this way 'cause I thought the renderer initialization time was too costly... I wonder if it would be better for me to just create new renderer instances so I can operate a concurrent PDF generation queue... and there you go, I went off on a tangent. Anyway can you confirm my findings? :)

Comment: Since the `ITextRenderer` has no method to clear i wouldn't reuse it. However (if possible) you should try using a instance per generation. For me it sounds plausible that FS has some trouble if you use one renderer for concurrently generating documents.

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing me out in that particular direction. I've posted a query in the FS google groups to verify if it's safe to reuse the renderer instance. I'll post any replies I get here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I've encountered is basically **accessing the same ITextRenderer instance concurrently on different threads, thus messing with the processing of the currently running PDF generation job.**

I've made the Executor service just use 1 thread and made the generation jobs sequential, and based on my observation, I can reuse the same ITextRenderer as long as I do the processing one at a time.

I've sent a query to confirm this with the devs of the Flying Saucer lib, I'll just update this post when they reply.

As an aside, I just have to figure out if it's more efficient to generate using 1 thread and 1 pre-instantiated ITextRenderer instance or use multiple threads but instantiate the ITextRenderer per-thread.

Comment: Did you ever think to instantiate the ITextRenderer per PDF generation? I'm finding long-lived ITextRenderers are caching up to 32 images in it's 'context', which is causing my out of memory errors.

Comment: @AnthonyChuinard this is actually pretty useful info... Have been getting some OOM errors as well in my app recently. Thanks.